# Which modifies which

Tags: adverbs, modifiers

> He took his son **back to school.**

Does **to school** modifies **back** or the other way around？

Comment: How do you justify either as a modifier of the other?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out. But I know ,theoretically , there must be a head and a modifier.

Comment: "To school" is complement of "back".

Comment: @Robbie Part of the problem is that your question’s text is ungrammatical. The simplest way to make it grammatical is to change “Is” to “Does”. That’s how I parsed your question, which is why I thought you made the implicit claim that a modifier exists at all in that phrase. After you have corrected the grammar of your question, consider adding an explanation of what you consider to be a modifier. I’m not a linguist, so perhaps my intuition is just uninformed, but I don’t find it natural to consider “back” a modifier of “to school”; the reverse is arguable, but seems to me to be a stretch.

Comment: //He took his son back to school.//  Here 'back to school' is an adverbial, and answers a possible question "Where did he take his son to?"  The skeleton sentence is "He took his son back"  It can also be read with a pause after back.

Comment: @Ram Pillai ,But you can also view the skeleton sentence as "He took his son to school.", which is also a logical answer to the question "Where did he take his son to?"  In this case, back（adverb）modifies "to school"(PP). "Back" expresses an additional meaning "the place they are going to is where he originally belong."

Comment: @Robby: In 'He took his son back to school',  He (is subj) took (is verb) son (is obj.), like S - V - O.  Rest are flesh to the bone.  To the question "whether 'to school' modifes back, or 'back' modies to school, my view is that it together functions as an adverbial to the verb 'took'. It is like 'up the hill' or 'down the valleys. Without 'to school',  the word 'back' functions as a one-word adverb.

Comment: There's no modification involved. The PP "to school" is complement of "back". The matrix PP "back to school" is an adjunct of place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submit "to school" thoroughly informs the reader of the end location of the boy, as well as the starting point of the boy, beyond the vague, "He took his son back.". The man's son had been at a certain place, school. Then the boy was elsewhere, due to some unstated cause. Next the boy  was returned to the original place, school, by his father.